# Get / Set on a Dynamic Object in Haxe using Reflect and String id

Tags: actionscript-3, haxe, haxeflixel

I have this actionScript3 Code I'm porting to haxe.

```
public static const DATA_COMPLETE_LEVELS : String   = "save_game_data_complete_levels";
private var _completedLevelKeys:Vector.<String>;


public function get completedLevelKeys():Vector.<String> {
    if (this.data[DATA_COMPLETE_LEVELS])
        return (Vector.<String>)(this.data[DATA_COMPLETE_LEVELS]);
    return null;

}           
public function set completedLevelKeys(value:Vector.<String>):void {
    if(value)
        this.data[DATA_COMPLETE_LEVELS] = (Vector.<String>)(value);
}
```

I'm just getting my hands dirty with haxe, andI got a bit confused with Reflect

What is the equivalent code in Haxe ?

Comment: What is the private var for? It doesn't seem like it is used at all.

Comment: You're right, I was probably meaning to check if null in get/set,  and update the private var accordingly when I designed the Class. But while implementing it I realized I don't need to update this var, just the .data object. I'll think about removing the private Declaration. Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
public static inline var DATA_COMPLETE_LEVELS = "save_game_data_complete_levels";

public var completedLevelKeys(get, set) : Vector<String>;

function get_completedLevelKeys() : Vector<String>
    return Reflect.field(this.data, DATA_COMPLETE_LEVELS);

function set_completedLevelKeys(values : Vector<String>) : Vector<String>
{
    if(null != values)
        Reflect.setField(this.data, DATA_COMPLETE_LEVELS, values);
    return values;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You meant this of course (Haxe 3+)

```
function get_completedLevelKeys() : Vector<String>

function set_completedLevelKeys(values : Vector<String>) : Vector<String>
```

Comment: you are right, although you might better write this as a comment of the already accepted answer